# For a Rails and GraphQL project, how do you define multiple queries with the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, graphql

Here's some context: I'm using Rails 5.1.4, Ruby 2.6.1, and GraphQL 1.9. I have my Rails project currently configured as a REST api only project. However, I'm starting to convert it to using GraphQL. After running the graphql related generators, I currently have a `graphql_controller.rb` file and a `query_type.rb` file.

For my database model, I have a `SchoolCourse` model which describes a particular course taught in college. For this model, I've defined a `school_course_type.rb`. In my `query_type.rb` file, I've defined a field for the `schoolCourse` query.

However, there are 2 types of users who can log into my application - teachers and students. If the user is a teacher, then accessing the application and querying for `schoolCourse` will return all the school courses that this particular instructor teachers. If the user is a student, then accessing the application and querying for `schoolCourse` will return all the school courses that this particular student attends. In both cases, the `schoolCourse` data is the same type (`school_course_type`).

I currently have the `schoolCourse` query defined in `query_type.rb` to work for teachers. However, if I want to extend the `schoolCourse` query to work for students as well, it seems like I'll have to update the `schoolCourse` query to include `if / else` logic to look something like this:

```
# This is how it currently looks like:

def schoolCourses
  teacher_user = context[:current_user]
  teacher_user.school_courses
end


# This is how I think it would change:

def schoolCourses
  user = context[:current_user]

  if user.type == 'teacher'
    user.school_courses
  else
    # different way for students to retrieve school courses
  end
end
```

While this may work, this isn't ideal. **The main problem I want to solve is to have multiple `schoolCourse` queries defined and have it so that teachers use one version and students use the other version.**

In my current application, I have 2 `schoolCourse` controllers - one for teachers and one for students, and by splitting it into two files, my API is much cleaner. **Is there any way to do something similar with the `query_type.rb` file where I have a query_type for teachers and another for students?** How have you dealt with this problem in your projects?

**Adding more context - 9/20/2019 2:10pm PST**

1. **How are school courses differentiated between student and teacher?** So school course objects are identical for both students and teachers. Currently in my RESTful backend, I have 2 separate controller files for getting student courses. One is for teachers and the other is for students. When the teacher's school course controller gets called, it's only returning the school courses for the logged in teacher. Similarly, when the student's school course controller gets called, it's only returning the school courses for the logged in student.
2. **Can you elaborate on why you want to have multiple school course queries?** The reason why I'm thinking I want multiple school course queries is because I don't want to have to add `if / else` logic inside the single school course query to do something for teachers and something else for students. I know it'll work but I probably have 50 other models and I don't have to put the same type of `if / else` logic inside each query.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information on how school courses are differentiated between student and teacher. Can you elaborate on why you want to have multiple school course queries?

You can define using Interface:

Types will become something like following:

```
module Types
  module Output
    StudentCourse = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
      name "StudentCourse"

      interfaces [CourseInterface]

      field :student_specific_field, Types::Output::SpecificField

    end
  end
end

module Types
  module Output
    TeacherCourse = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
      name "TeacherCourse"

      interfaces [CourseInterface]

      field :teacher_specific_field, Types::Output::SpecificField

    end
  end
end

module Types
  module Output
    CourseInterface = GraphQL::InterfaceType.define do
      name "Course"

      resolve_type lambda { |context, obj, _|
        case context[:user].type?
        when student
          Types::Output::StudentCourse
        when teacher
          Types::Output::TeacherCourse
        else
          raise Types::CantResolveType, "can't resolve type: #{obj.class}"
        end
      }

      field :id, !types.ID
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tanay - I went ahead and added more context to my initial post based on your questions. Let me know if the context helps with coming up with a solution.

Comment: I like this response, except for defining different types if the underlying model/schema is the same whether student or teacher. If the schemas are the same, you're essentially asking for different records from the same table to be returned. This to me boils down to a where clause in a SQL query or just an Active Record scope on the course model. I would only reach for different types if you've got different course models suggesting that the fields are different which further suggests that they're different course types